# Compute win/lose chances picking two integers in different overlapping intervals

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm asking some help to compute a probability formula, as I'm not sure of my computation and approximation.

The problem:
Two players P1 and P2 pick a random integer in different number ranges, the problem is to compute the probability of lose of P1.

- a, b, n are positive integers
- b > a
- n < (b - a)    (The two intervals have common values)
- in case of equality, P1 lose

P1 picks a number in [a,b] 
P2 picks a number in [a+n,b+n]

My try to estimate the % of lose of P1:

1. Always lose cases
   P1 always lose is it picks a number between [a, a+n]
   Always loose ratio: n/(b-a)
2. Lose % for P1
   When P1 pick a number x over a+n, the probability of lose are:
   (b+n-x)/(b-a)
   Each one has a probability of 1/(b-a)
   formula would be:
   SUM((b+n-x)/(b-a)², x=a+n..b+n)

   But my interval are big with no real way to compute that sum.

   Can this be appoximated by the using the average value of each interval ?
   P1 average: a+(b-a)/2 = (b-a)/2
   P2 average: a+n+(b-a)/2 = n + (b-a)/2

   So probability P1 lose would be:
   ((n + (b-a)/2) - ((b-a)/2))/(b-a)

   So: n/(b-a)+1/2

For the global:
n/(b-a)+(1-n/(b-a))*(n/(b-a)+1/2)

That's OK ? or ?
Many thanks for the review !

Comment: I believe you are suffering from some off-by-one errors in your analysis. You said that the probability of $P_1$ picking a number in $[a,a+n]$ is $n/(b-a)$. The probability is actually $(n+1)/(b-a+1)$, since there are $n+1$ numbers in the range $\{a,a+1,\dots,a+n\}$, and $b-a+1$ numbers in the range $\{a,a+1,\dots,b\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way to calculate this. There are three ways that $P_1$ can lose.

- As you noted, if $P_1$ chooses strictly less than $a+n$, then she automatically loses. The probability of this occurring is $\frac{n}{b-a+1}$, as there are $n$ numbers in $\{a,a+1,\dots,a+n-1\}$, and $b-a+1$ numbers in $\{a,a+1,\dots,b\}$.
- Similarly, if $P_2$ chooses a number which is strictly more than $b$, then $P_1$ will certainly lose. The probability of this is also $\frac{n}{b-a+1}$.
- The probability that neither of the previous situations happens is
  $$
  \left(1-\frac{n}{b-a+1}\right)^2
  $$
  Furthermore, conditional on neither of these events happening, both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are picking numbers from the same range, $\{a+n,a+n+1,\dots, b\}$. There are two things that can happen.

  - If $P_1$ and $P_2$ pick the same number, then $P_1$ loses. This happens with probability $\frac1{b-a-n+1}$ (why?).
  - Conditional on them picking different numbers, $P_1$ wins exactly half the time, by symmetry.

Putting this altogether,
$$
\mathbb P(P_1 \text{ wins})=
\underbrace{\left(1-\frac{n}{b-a+1}\right)^2}
_{\text{Probability that $P_1\ge a+n$ and $P_2\le b$.}}
\times 
\underbrace{\left(1-\frac{1}{b-a-n+1}\right)}_
\text{Conditional probability $P_1\neq P_2$}
\times 
\underbrace{\frac12}
_\text{Conditional probability $P_1>P_2$.}
$$

Comment: Many thanks for the detailled explanation.

Comment: Why P1 lose in case of draw ? 
This is to give a small advantage to P2, which will "create a game", on the contrary P1 can choose its oponent from the available games and picks the game proposed by P2.

I will use your formula to adjust the parameters of the dApp game I'm currently implementing on the Ergo blockchain.